# JavaScript - Why can I only access certain variables from within a function?

Tags: javascript, scope

**Sample 1:**

```
var someText = "Ein Hund kam in die Küche und stahl dem Koch ein Ei.";          // Some Strings      
var moreText = "Da nahm der Koch den Löffel und schlug den Hund entzwei.";

var someNumber = 34;                                                            // Some Numbers
var anotherNumber = 98;
         

function testFunc(){
    var box_uno = document.getElementById("output1");       // "output1" references a <textarea>
    box_uno.innerHTML = someText;
}
```

**Sample 2:**

```
var someText = "Ein Hund kam in die Küche und stahl dem Koch ein Ei.";          // Some Strings      
var moreText = "Da nahm der Koch den Löffel und schlug den Hund entzwei.";

var someNumber = 34;                                                            // Some Numbers
var anotherNumber = 98;
         
var box_uno = document.getElementById("output1");       // "output1" references a <textarea>

function testFunc(){
    box_uno.innerHTML = someText;
}
```

**Sample 1** works fine. The string is displayed in the textarea as expected.

**Sample 2** doesn't work and I'd like to fully understand why. I thought variables which are declared outside of a function have global scope.
I don't get why I can access the variables with strings and numbers from inside the function, but not the variable containing a html-element.

Comment: If you want to set the value of a textarea, you should use `.value`, not `.innerHTML`. `.innerHTML` won't work when the value has previously been populated, eg by user input.

Comment: Most likely related to [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14028959/1048572)